# How to match a string in array on keyup event?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please first read my requirement i just explain you.

> I have a array (size=8264 or length),which store all data.

now i have a input box in which write any character ok
i want to implement match a string which is input by user.

```
    case 1:
       if user input key then after search.
    case 2 :
       if user change text then searching loop will be stop 
       and again search with new string in array.
//my code on keyup event
var stationName = ["LAKHO - LAK", "LUSHALA - LAL", "LOTANA - LAN", "LOHAPUR - LAP", "LALITPUR - LAR", "LATHI - LAT", "LADNUN - LAU", "LAUL - LAUL", "LABHA - LAV", "LAMBHUA - LBA", "LIMBODRA - LBD", "LIMBGAON - LBG", "LILABARI - LBI", "LABAN - LBN", "LABPUR - LBP", "LUCKNOW CITY - LC", "LALBAGH CRT RD - LCAE", "LINCH - LCH", "LACHMANPUR ROAD - LCME", "LALPUR CHANDRA - LCN",  "DEORI - DOE", "DHODRA MOHAR - DOH", "DEVGARH MADRIYA - DOHM", "DHOLKA - DOK", "DUKHERI - DOKY", "DHOLI - DOL", "DHOLIKUA - DOLK", "DUNDARA - DOR", "DEHRI ON SONE - DOS", "JHANJHARPUR - JJP", "JEJURI - JJR"];
stationName.sort();

function searchStationName(obj, event) {
    if ((!obj) || (!event))
        return;
    if (obj.value.length == 0)
        return;
    var tempText = '', regVar = '';
    var tempLength = 0;
    var statNameArray = [];
    var arrayKeyCode = [144, 9, 20, 17, 91, 32, 13, 46, 18, 16];
    var keycodeVal = event.keyCode;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (keycodeVal == arrayKeyCode[i])
            return;
    }
        tempText = obj.value;
        tempLength = stationName.length;
        regVar = tempText.toUpperCase();
       for (var i = 0; i < tempLength; i++) {
                if (stationName[i].match(regVar)) {
                    statNameArray[count] = stationName[i];
                    }
        }
 }
```

so How can i implement this please help me

Note: code pure in javascript

Comment: Ask a clear and specific question. Also put the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: I still dont understand the question. Can you be more specific please? You want to search for an value of the array?

Comment: What have you done? So far you're giving us tasks...

Comment: Almost looks like he wants an autocomplete function based off of an array of names, so if he starts typing in "JE" it autocompletes with JEJURI - JJR

Comment: Hello sir you are absolutely right please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id='arraymatched'>

</div>

arr_0 = ["0","2","3"]
arr_2 = ["2","8","8"];

document.getElementById("arraymatched").innerHTML = arraymatch(arr_0,arr_2);

function arraymatch(arr_0,arr_2)
{
var arrmatch = [];
for(i = 0; i <= arr_0.length; i++){
 for(j = 0; j <= arr_2.length; j++){
    if(arr_0[i] == arr_2[j]){
      arrmatch.push(arr_0[i]);
    }
 }
}
return arrmatch;
}
```

Comment: send a string instated of number as array

Comment: Hello i want to search not compare ok it input field only one array you have in which i want search with dynamic string

Comment: Please check your sentence than "now i have a input box in which write any character ok i want to implement match a string which is input by user."